# How can I open and auto-dismiss an Alert Dialog when opening a new section?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to have a dialog pop up on screen when case 2 is selected from the Action bar, preferably without clicking on a button. As of right now, I can only get it to work onClick and not when the page opens. How can I get rid of the button and only have it show on open for a few seconds, then dismiss? Thanks.

```
case 2:
                // get button
                Button btnShow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_show);
                btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Auto-closing Dialog");
                        builder.setMessage("After 2 second, this dialog will be closed automatically!");
                        builder.setCancelable(true);

                        final AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();

                        dlg.show();

                        final Timer t = new Timer();
                        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                            public void run() {
                                dlg.dismiss(); // when the task active then close the dialog
                                t.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread, otherwise, you may receive a crash report
                            }
                        }, 2000); // after 2 second (or 2000 miliseconds), the task will be active.

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Handle for your requirement :

```
case 2:
                // get button
                Button btnShow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_show);
                btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Auto-closing Dialog");
                        builder.setMessage("After 2 second, this dialog will be closed automatically!");
                        builder.setCancelable(true);

                        final AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();

                        dlg.show();

                        Handler mHandler = new handler();
            Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable () {

                public void run() {
                    if(dlg != null && dlg.isShowing()) dlg.dismiss();
                }
            };
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,2000);

                    }
                });
```

**UPDATE :**

I have updated code for removing errors

This code will dismiss the alert dialog after 2 seconds user clicks on button.
Is this what you want to do ?

Comment: Thanks for this. Using it gives an error for `Handler mHandler = new handler();` "Cannot resolve symbol 'handler'".

Comment: Import Handler class first

Comment: Ok, I got that working,  now there seems to be some issues with missing `(` after that. I apologize, I am new to Android dev, so this may be something simple. [link](http://puu.sh/gGHA8/c73df2a4b4.png) - There are some errors there that I cannot resolve.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake in `(` and `}` I have updated my code above. Please check

Comment: thanks, that resolved the `(` but now I am getting some errors with the `Runnable` item [link](http://puu.sh/gGIpu/e65a569899.png)

Comment: you have not copied code perfect `Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable ()`.Please copy again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73353/discussion-between-holdfast33-and-kushal).

Comment: This is still working as I originally coded. I need it to pop-up automatically when the section is selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the Button and want to have click functionalty use :

```
Button btnShow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_show);
btnShow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
btnShow.performClick();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Doing this creates an error for `(View v)` and `(v.getContext()` "Cannot resolve symbol 'v'"

Comment: I would also like to perform this, without having to click anything if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not understand what you are trying to say.Your following statement is making confusion

> I am trying to have a dialog pop up on screen when case 2 is selected
>   from the Activity bar,

I do not know what do you meant by case 2 and activity bar. but in case if it is actionbar and you are using spinner in it then you can override the following method

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                //Here you can implement the case
```

so when you are able to show the dialog box, You can start timer with the start of dialog box and you can then on finish of timer you can close the dialog box.

I hope this make sense to you. Please reply back if you need help I can provide source code.

Comment: Im sorry my question was confusing. I am new to android dev. I have a 3 section app from the templates. I want to have the popup open when I open section 2 then close a few seconds later.

Comment: please share your class

Answer (score 0):

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
      Runnable hideDialog = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              dialog.dismiss();
         }
    };
    executor.schedule(hideDialog, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```